# Instagram iphone hooks description

Tags: ios, iphone, hook, instagram

I'm trying to create an application where it opens instagram after editing the picture in my app. I wanted it to include a hashtag on the description when it goes to instagram but I seem to get lost on how to implement that. The iphone hooks states to use the tag line but I don't know where to place that. below is my code

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
docInteraction.delegate = self;
Saves the edited Image to directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instaFilterx.jpg"];
UIImage *image = combinedImage;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

    //Loads the edited Image
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instaFilterx.jpg"];
UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];

Hooks the edited Image with Instagram
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/instaFilterx.igo"];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

Prepares the DocumentInteraction with the .igo image for Instagram
NSURL *instagramImageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:jpgPath];
docInteraction = [UIDocumentInteractionController
interactionControllerWithURL:instagramImageURL];
[docInteraction setUTI:@"com.instagram.exclusivegram"];eciate any help. Thank you.
```

Answer (score 0):

To add caption to your Instagram Post. Do the following:

```
docInteraction.annotation=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your #Text", @"InstagramCaption", nil];
```

Hope this helps.